# Serverless-webpack not including `pg` package

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typeorm, serverless

I'm trying to modify a code generated from `aws-nodejs-typescript` template. I've installed `typeorm`, `reflect-metadata` and `pg` to work with PostgreSQL.

They are in `dependencies` in `package.json`
[image]

The webpack config is the default one

```js
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

/*
This line is only required if you are specifying `TS_NODE_PROJECT` for whatever reason.
 */
// delete process.env.TS_NODE_PROJECT;

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: './tsconfig.paths.json',
      }),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false,
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**The problem:** after `sls deploy` the `zip` archive does not contain the `pg` package and hence requests fail as `Postgres package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install pg --save`. How do I fix this?

I suspect this might be happening because of a dynamic dependency resolution or whatever as there is no direct dependency in my code and `typeorm` decides which driver to use based on string in connection configuration.

P.S. `sls offline` works so the code should be correct and the problem is around this not included package to zip archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you're right, there's probably no direct dependency and you use a dynamic requires, i.e. you require modules that are only known at runtime.

So you need to force adding it using the following:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
       forceInclude:
         - pg
```

See [forced inclusion](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#forced-inclusion) in [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack).

Comment: I already have `includeModules: true` how do I extend it?

Comment: Tried this code as is. Seems to be working and not including Node's packages which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's working fine.. Thanks.

& For typescript project you need to write

`custom: {webpack: {webpackConfig: './webpack.config.js',includeModules:{ forceInclude: ["pg"] }},}`